# asp.net mvc web application prompting user name and password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a asp.net mvc web application hosted in IIS. The functionality is to list the files kept in a folder PDFFiles.

PDFFiles folder is in another server. Now when ever I try to get the mvc screen to view the files, it is asking for user name and password 3 times. Even if I am giving the credentials, it is not showing the details list.

Is it due to some permission issue?

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could found the solution. IIS server needs to give the permission to the mentioned folder. Once the permission is set, I could access the files. Thank you.